# How to get rid of extra print statement on my loop

Tags: java

Guys i would like to ask how to get rid of the "and" print on my loop

2 and 4 and <

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Methods(5);
}

public static void Methods(int a){

    int loops = a/2;
    int even = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < loops; i++){
        even+=2;
        System.out.print(even+" and ");
    }
}
```

it prints

2 and 4 and <<<

Instead i want

2 and 4 <<<

thank you.
Please help me i am beginner T_T

Comment: check [StringUtils.join in Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
public static void Methods(int a){
   int loops = a/2;
   int even = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < loops; i++){
       even+=2;

       System.out.print(even);
       if (i < loops - 1) {
           System.out.print(" and ")
       }
   }
```

In other words: as long as `i` is smaller than `loops - 1` (which holds during your entire loop except the last step) you would print out `" and "`. This ensures the last `and` is not printed when it goes through the loop the last time.

Answer (score 1):

Test if your index is the last index you would be on, i.e. if `i == loops - 1`.  If so, then just print `even` instead of `even + " and "`.

Comment: Sir it will just print 4 if i use that i want to print 2 and 4 < i just got extra and < i want my program to determine even numbers of the given number. for example 10 < i want to print 2 and 4 and 6 and 8 and 10. thank you :D

Comment: Yes, it will print `4`.  The first iteration should print `2 and `, and the second iteration will print `4`, yielding `2 and 4`.

Answer (score 0):

Before entering the loop check if there is an element, print just the first element. Increment `i` and then for each remaining element always pre-pend `" and "` first.

```
int i = 0;
if (i < loops) {
    even+=2;
    System.out.print(even);
}
i++;
for(; i < loops; i++){
    even+=2;

    System.out.print(" and " + even);
}
```

This way you avoid all the checking inside the loop.